# Jest: reuse previous coverage when Running coverage on untested files

Tags: code-coverage, jestjs, istanbul

**Scenario**
I am running jest (or a React project) to test my files.

**Goal**
I would like to see the coverage report for all my source files and then by running jest in `--watch` mode see only the changed files report change (hopefully improve) while leaving the untested files report untouched.

**Problem**
Right now, while running `jest --config=config/jest/config.json --watch --coverage`, and using the configuration `"collectCoverageFrom": ["src/**/*.{tsx,ts}"]` the coverage related with the modified file are updated properly BUT the coverage for the UNTESTED files goes back to 0% (since no test where run for those files and any previous test run got forgotten)

**Question**
Is there a way to retain the old tests coverage reports for the untested files?

**Why?**
Imagine us having 100 files in the src folder. At the beginning all the coverage is 0%. Then you start jest in watch mode and you fix 1 file. The coverage shows 100% for that file, 0% for the other files. Total coverage of 1%.

Then you change a second file (the day after). Your total coverage should be 2%, instead since TODAY you changed only 1 file, the overall coverage is reported as 1%.

The correct total coverage is reported only when you run a full test+report without using the watch mode, but this makes the process non-practical since I would like to fix progressively my tests, watch for file changes and see the coverage grow as I fix.

**Similar reported issues**
https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2256 it was closed by I still don't understand how it would fix the problem

**Ideas**
I don't mind if to have this report I need to adapt jest/istanbul to do some magic merge of reports. I tried to follow some comments on github but couldn't come up with something that works

Comment: Did you find any solution to this meanwhile?